# Get user current coordinates with MKMapView (objective c, xcode 6)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

My code is as follows:

```
#import "radSecondViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface radSecondViewController ()

@end

CLLocationManager *locationManager = nil;

@implementation radSecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocation *oldLocation;
    if (locations.count > 1) {
        oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:locations.count-2];
    } else {
        oldLocation = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);
    MKCoordinateRegion userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 1500.0, 1500.0);
}
//snipped memory dump
@end
```

As you can see I am trying to have the console log the change in coordinates every time it happens.

However when I build the app, nothing is output to the console. When I add breakpoints to the `locationManager:updateLocation...` line, they are never hit.

I have set the location to several places (Apple, Freeway Drive, etc.) in the simulator.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and found a fix? Or is this a rookie mistake I'm making? I am new to Xcode and Objective C.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the location manager's `delegate` property.

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

And update your class extension to be:

```
@interface radSecondViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end
```

And change the line:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = nil;
```

to be inside the `@imlpementation` block:

```
@implementation radSecondViewController {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = nil;
}
```

As you have it, it is declared as a global variable instead of an instance variable.